# Programmer for MSP430F2274 TI microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, programmer, texas-instruments

I want to program that specific microcontroller (MSP430F2274) and i would like to hear your opinion on what programmer to choose . I prefer one that can be used with a linux machine.

So what you suggest me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSP430 can be programmed with either four-wire JTAG or a two-wire TI-specific variant called Spy-Bi-Wire. The official programmer-debugger is called the [MSP-FET](http://www.ti.com/tool/msp-fet), which supports both four-wire JTAG and Spy-Bi-Wire. If this is for commercial development, you probably want to use this programmer.

For production purposes, TI sells the [MSP-GANG](http://www.ti.com/tool/msp-gang) 8-controller in-circuit gang programmer.

If you're just a hobbyist, however, the MSP430 can be programmed (Spy-Bi-Wire only) using the [MSP430 Launchpad](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/launchpads-msp430-msp-exp430g2.html) dev kit. DIP package versions can be plugged into the board for programming. For SMT versions, break the Spy-By-Wire pins out to a header on your PCB and make a cable so you can make the appropriate connections to the Launchpad. I've done this with a couple of boards and it is fairly effective.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the "DRIVERS" section in the [mspdebug manual](http://mspdebug.sourceforge.net/manual.html) for the full list.

The cheapest option is probably the Launchpad board, and it is already connected to a target, so you can do a simple LED-blink example to get started and prove that the tools are set up properly.  Then break out the SBW lines to your msp430f2274 target.

On Ubuntu, you can "sudo apt-get install gcc-msp430 mspdebug" and have a working toolchain.